# Python - sample between 3 distributions with weights

Tags: python

I have three distributions `disbn_1`, `disbn_2` and `disbn_3`. I want to sample 10m variates from these three distributions with a weight attached to each one. The idea I had was to sample 10m variates from each distribution and then "choose" which distribution to use based on the weight by sampling random variates (or using the np.random.choice function). However, I could not get this work. What I am trying to obtain is an array of size 10m which is sampled from three distributions with the weights `w_1`,`w_2`,`w_3` for each distribution.

The code below shows where I am, I want to sample from `arr_1`,`arr_2`,`arr_3` with the provided weights. Speed is a concern here so need something fairly efficient. I also set up an approach with generators but python does not sample again when I call the generator

Any help would be appreciated:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import scipy.stats as sp

#exponential 1
min_1 = 10_000_000
max_1 = 8_000_000_000
par_1 = 1000 #
w_1 = 0.75 

disbn_1 = sp.expon(scale=par_1)

#exponential 3
min_2 = 2000000
max_2 = max_1
par_2 = 1.6 # 
w_2 = 0.2

disbn_2 = sp.pareto(par_2,scale=min_2) #not there is already a minimum not scaling it again when simulating

#exponential 2
min_3 = 1000000
max_3 = max_1
par_3 = 455555 # 
w_3 = 0.05

disbn_3 = sp.expon(scale=par_3)


#checking if distributions match back up

n_sample = 10_000_000
arr_1 = np.clip(disbn_1.rvs(n_sample)+min_1,a_min = 0,a_max = max_1) 
arr_2 = np.clip(disbn_2.rvs(n_sample),a_min = 0,a_max = max_2)
arr_3 = np.clip(disbn_3.rvs(n_sample)+min_3,a_min = 0,a_max = max_3)

#want to sample from arr_1,arr_2 and arr_3 with weights w_1,w_2,w_3 10m samples


#alternative approach - set up generators
generators = [
    np.clip(disbn_1.rvs()+min_1,a_min = 0,a_max = max_1),
    np.clip(disbn_2.rvs(),a_min = 0,a_max = max_2), #see no addtional + min_2 as disbn already starts
    np.clip(disbn_3.rvs()+min_3,a_min = 0,a_max = max_3)
]

draw = np.random.choice([0,1,2],3,p=[w_1,w_2,w_3])
arr = np.array([generators[i] for i in draw]) #does not work as generator[i] does not give me a new sample
```

Comment: I see a series of statements, but I’m afraid you’ve forgotten to ask a *specific* question. And “could not get this work” is far too broad.

Comment: @S3DEV What I am trying to obtain is an array of size 10m which is sampled from three distributions with the weights `w_1`,`w_2`,`w_3` for each distribution. I have edited the main post.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, it is fairly simple:

```py
gens = [
    lambda n: np.clip(disbn_1.rvs(n) + min_1, a_min=0, a_max=max_1),
    lambda n: np.clip(disbn_2.rvs(n), a_min=0, a_max=max_2),
    lambda n: np.clip(disbn_3.rvs(n) + min_3, a_min=0, a_max=max_3),
]

n_sample = 10_000_000
n = np.round(np.array([w_1, w_2, w_3]) * n_sample).astype(int)

>>> n
array([7500000, 2000000,  500000])
```

Now:

```py
x = np.concatenate([gi(ni) for gi, ni in zip(gens, n)])
np.random.shuffle(x)

>>> x.shape
(10000000,)
```

Now, in `x`, you have the mixed samples from the three distributions with the respective weights you wanted.

For a quick plot:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
a, bins, o = ax.hist(samp, bins=500, density=True, log=True, alpha=.4)
ylim = ax.get_ylim()
# just for plotting
xmax = 3e9
x = np.linspace(bins.min(), xmax, num=200)
ax.plot(x, w_1 * disbn_1.pdf(x))
ax.plot(x, w_2 * disbn_2.pdf(x))
ax.plot(x, w_3 * disbn_3.pdf(x))
ax.set_ylim(ylim)
ax.set_xlim(None, xmax)
plt.show()
```

[image]